# wrong linux-headers-server version

Tags: server, apt, dependencies

On my Ubuntu 12.04 server I get the message that `linux-server` depends on `linux-headers-server` 3.2.0.55.65 but 3.2.0.56.66 is installed.

The suggested `apt-get -f install` won't work.

my sources.list:

```
    # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ precise main restricted

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Comment: Dependencies are unmet. Tell the Ubuntu version and the Method you followed to install.

Comment: Version: Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS Method: cron update (/etc/cron.daily/apt)

Comment: Problem is linux-headers-server installed with [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=names&keywords=linux-headers-server). But there is no `linux-headers-server 3.2.0.55.65` even in Lucid in Ubuntu repositories. So you may have tried tried to install  `linux-server` with Other Repository. So remove that Repository and do the installation again with `sudo apt-get install linux-server`.

Comment: The server wasn't touched for about 2 Months. So nothing was added and nothing was changed manually. Since 09.11 I get the error by Email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-server

sudo apt-get install linux-server
```

Answer (score 0):

`df -h`

check if /boot is 100% full or has enough space?

`/dev/sda1                        228M  133M   84M  100% /boot`

### IF full free up some space

take a look at what version you're running with

`uname -a`

**Example:**

`Linux YOURSERVERNAME 3.2.0-70-generic #105-Ubuntu UTC ... GNU/Linux`

notice `3.2.0-XX-generic` for me it was `70` yours might be lower... higher just depends

everything before `70` can be removed for my example. recommended to leave a rollback version  so everything before `68`

The goal here is to **free up some space**

#### DON'T COPY THIS CHECK YOUR OWN MACHINE

BE CAREFUL

`rm abi-3.2.0-XX-generic`

`rm config-3.2.0-XX-generic`

`rm initrd.img-3.2.0-XX-generic`

`rm System.map-3.2.0-XX-generic`

once you have freed up some space

`df -h` try to get USE% to a reasonable amount for installs

`/dev/sda1 XX% /boot`

`sudo apt-get -f install`

`sudo apt-get autoclean`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`